# Python tkinter cannot update a window in a while loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a main screen that changes to a homepage after user logged in. If I change while loop it never prints or opens login page. Now I changed it but whenever i logged in the login def returns true but main.py keeps it as False.
main.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from login import LoginNP

class NP:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        self.root.title("New Project")

        self.buton = Button(text="Giriş yap", command=self.loginPage).pack(anchor=NE)

        self.title_frame = Frame(borderwidth=5,height=150,width=300, relief=RIDGE)
        self.title_frame.pack(anchor=N)
        self.welcome_label = Label(self.title_frame, text="Hello", height=10, width=10).pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        while True:
            root.update_idletasks()
            root.update()
            if not self.checkLogin():
                break
            else:
                pass

    def checkLogin(self):
        if LoginNP.loginMessage:
            print("A")
            return True
        else:
            print("B")
            return False

    def loginPage(self):
        self.new_win = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.new_obj = LoginNP(self.new_win)
        self.new_win.attributes('-topmost', True)



class HomePage:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        self.root.title("Homepage")


        self.title_frame = Frame(self.root, height=500, width=300)
        self.title_frame.pack(anchor=CENTER, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.welcome_label = Label(self.title_frame, text="Homepage", height=10, width=10).pack(padx=10, pady=5)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    root=Tk()
    obj=NP(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I want to update my NP window with Homepage window but in while loop program not getting result from login.py

login.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox

con = sqlite3.connect("npdb.db")
cur = con.cursor()

class LoginNP:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("350x240")
        self.root.title("Login Page")

        #vars
        self.username_var = StringVar()
        self.password_var = StringVar()

        #frames
        self.upper_frame = Frame(self.root, height=70)
        self.upper_frame.pack(anchor=N, fill=X, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.middle_frame = Frame(self.root, height=70)
        self.middle_frame.pack(anchor=CENTER, fill=X, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.lower_frame = Frame(self.root, height=70)
        self.lower_frame.pack(anchor=S, fill=X, padx=10, pady=5)

        #label&entry
        self.username_label = Label(self.upper_frame, text="Username: ").pack(anchor=W, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.username_entry = Entry(self.upper_frame, textvariable=self.username_var).pack(anchor=W, padx=10, pady=5, fill=X)

        self.password_label = Label(self.middle_frame, text="Password: ").pack(anchor=W, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.password_entry = Entry(self.middle_frame, textvariable=self.password_var, show="*").pack(anchor=W, padx=10, pady=5, fill=X)

        self.login_btn = Button(self.lower_frame, text="Login", command=self.loginMessage).grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.register_btn = Button(self.lower_frame, text="Register",command=self.register).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=205, pady=5)

    @property
    def login(self):
        with con:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user_database WHERE username=:username", {'username': self.username_var.get()})
            if cur.fetchone() == None:
                return False
            else:
                cur.execute("SELECT password FROM user_database WHERE username=:username", {'username': self.username_var.get()})
        `enter code here`        row = cur.fetchone()
                return row[0] == self.password_var.get()

    def loginMessage(self):
        if self.login:
            messagebox.showerror(title="Approve!", message="Giriş Başarılı!")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(title="Deny!", message="Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı!")
        self.root.destroy()
        return self.login

    def search(self):
        with con:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user_database WHERE username=:username", {'username': self.username_var.get()})
            return len(cur.fetchall()) < 1

    def register(self):
        if self.username_var.get().strip() == "" or self.password_var.get().strip() == "":
            messagebox.showerror(title='Hata!', message="Lütfen boşluk bırakmayınız!")
        else:
            if not self.search():
                messagebox.showerror(title='Hata!', message="Kullanıcı adı zaten kayıtlı.\nLütfen başka bir kullanıcı adı alınız.")
            else:
                cur.execute("""INSERT INTO user_database VALUES (?, ?)""", (self.username_var.get(), self.password_var.get()))
                con.commit()


if __name__ =="__main__":
    root=Tk()
    obj=LoginNP(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using a while true loop in the vast majority of GUI's will freeze the GUI and completely block any user interaction with the program.

Comment: You should check `print( LoginNP.loginMessage )` to see what you really get. You should first create instance `win = LoginNP()` and later execute function `win.loginMessage()`. But maybe you should check `if LoginNP.login` instead of `loginMessage` - but this also need to create instance of `LoginNP()`. Maybe you should check login outside any GUI/Windows

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `if LoginNP.loginMessage:`  in `checkLogin` doesn't do what you think it does.

You have imported the `LoginNP` class, and `loginMessage` is a method of this class.

So, `if LoginNP.loginMessage:` basically means "does the class LoginNP have a method loginMessage". To which the answer is `True`.

But you are not instantiating an object of type `LoginNP` nor calling a method on that instance.

Check this example:

```
In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     def __init__():
   ...:         pass
   ...:     def bar():
   ...:         print("calling 'bar'")
   ...: 

In [2]: if Foo.bar:
   ...:     print(True)
   ...:     
True
```

And note the absence of the printed message `calling 'bar'`.